# Using ptr containers instead of normal containers gives _Block_Type_Is_Valid

Tags: c++, boost

```
class A {
public:
    void doSomething() {}
}
boost::unordered_map<int, boost::intrusive_ptr<A>> m;
m.insert(0, new A());
m.insert(1, new A());
m.insert(2, new A());

// later...
std::vector<boost::intrusive_ptr<A>> f;
boost::unordered_map<int, boost::intrusive_ptr<A>>::iterator i;

i = m.find(0);
f.push_back(i->second);
i = m.find(1);
f.push_back(i->second);
i = m.find(2);
f.push_back(i->second);

// and then do operations on f:
for(size_t i = 0; i < f.size(); ++i) {
    f[i].doSomething();
}
```

To:

```
class A {
public:
    void doSomething() {}
}
boost::ptr_unordered_map<int, A> m;
m.insert(0, new A());
m.insert(1, new A());
m.insert(2, new A());

// later...
boost::ptr_vector<A> f;
boost::ptr_unordered_map<int, A>::iterator i;

i = m.find(0);
f.push_back(i->second);
i = m.find(1);
f.push_back(i->second);
i = m.find(2);
f.push_back(i->second);

// and then do operations on f:
for(size_t i = 0; i < f.size(); ++i) {
    f[i].doSomething();
}
```

I useing ptr containers instead of normal containers and I getting `_Block_Type_Is_Valid (pHead->nBlockUse)` error.
With the normal containers version it worked just fine.

The problem is in `f.push_back(i->second);` because if I deleting those lines the program works fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unlike intrusive_ptr, there is no shared ownership **[¹]**

The ptr_vector takes ownership of the pointers you push_back into it.

Because there is no shared ownership, this results in a double free when the map goes out of scope.

Either store copies into your vector, or use shared ownership (shared_ptr)

---

**[¹]** I take it your first sample should look somewhat like this: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/cc228ec98163879e

Comment: Ohh right, and there no way to fix the second example (I want to keep my code clean...)?

Comment: Yes, e.g. **[like this](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/11cf86fd93f9cbd1)**. You'll agreee that it's not elegant, because ptr_vector just tries to have a polymorphic element but with unique ownership semantics ("values"). If you don't need that, consider Boost Intrusive containers.

Comment: Oh, to show copy construction as well: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/fc15cb05c6050f3a